# How to auto-increment values in ID column in OData

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a new record of user in my OData model. For every new record created, I want the `userId` to be self-created and auto-incremented for the next user to be added. The code is also not reading the success function and directly executing the error part when I applied the debugger and checked.

**signup.controller.js**

```js
return Controller.extend("Workspace.controller.App", {
  onInit: function() {
    var user = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
    var oModel = new JSONModel(user);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "SUP");
  },

  signupButton: function(oEvent) {
    var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("TEST");
    var oModel1 = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("UID");
    var oModel2 = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("SUP");
    var obj = {};
    obj.USERID = oModel1.getProperty("/x");
    obj.USERNAME = oModel2.getProperty("/name");
    obj.PASSWORD = oModel2.getProperty("/password");
    obj.USERMAIL = oModel2.getProperty("/email");

    oModel.create("/user", obj, {
      success: function(oData, oResponse) {
        MessageToast.show("Record Created Successfully...");

      },
      error: function(err, oResponse) {
        MessageToast.show("Record not Created...");
      }
    });
  },

  // ...
});
```

Comment: The ID should be created in the backend. Your console should tell you why you got an error and not a success.

Comment: I have created the Id in the backend only but I am unable to refer it and increment it

Comment: After creating the user, you can return the User details as a response for referring. Regarding the increment you are already doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the suggestion made by Marc, here's how you should do it.

1. In the createEntity method of "user", read the body(the obj in your oModel.create) sent by the UI request.
2. Read the user table(table data which constitutes the user entity Collection) and find the latest userID available.
3. Along with the data collected from step 1, insert the record with the userId you wish to insert.

Hope this helps in solving.

Comment: In step 2, how to find the latest userid available i.e. the data  of the last row

Comment: select the row with the highest userId value available.